# How to self-join two bags?

Tags: mapreduce, apache-pig

I have some set of numbers that describes connections between the first set of integers and the second set of integers. For example:

```
1,2
3,4
5,6
5,7
6,8
```

I then load my data as follows, and group it:

```
data = load 'data.csv' as integer_1, integer_2;
grouped = group data by integer_1;

grouped_numbers = foreach grouped generate group as node, data.integer_2 as connection;
```

Which then yields a bag with each first integer and its first-degree connections:

```
(1,{(2)})
(3,{(4)})
(5,{(6),(7)})
(6,{(8)})
```

I would then like to do a self-join of the grouped_numbers bag, in order to give the resultant first integer with each of its first- and second-degree connections. In this case, that would be:

```
(1,{(2)})
(3,{(4)})
(5,{(6),(7),(8)})
(6,{(8)})
```

because 5 is connected to 6, which is connected to 8, so 8 is a second-degree connection of 6. How would I implement this in Pig?

Answer (score 0):

First join:

```
    joined = join data1 by int_2, data2 by int_1
```

where data1 and data2 are the same set (copies of `data` in this example).

then group by the first field. The inner bag will have all the connections to the 'group', possibly more than once. So you might need a distinct on the inner bags as well, if you just one the unique elements.

(answered via a Pig mailing list)